# Standard database schema for police/law enforcement related work

Tags: database-design

I know there is a recommended schema for C2 Systems used by NATO

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JC3IEDM

May I know if there is a recommended schema for Police related work?

I am trying to migrate and coverage some legacy data related to law and enforcement work into a standard database.

Comment: Are you talking about arrest, suspect, and trial information, or something else related to police command and control?  In my opinion, the most important part of suspect information to get right is names, nicknames, and aliases.

Comment: I found this link.  Scroll down the middle column until you get to 14. Law Enforcement.  http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/  I couldn't follow any of the links because my prisons organization thinks that the links are malicious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Chapter 18 "Criminal Justice" of Enterprise Model Patterns by David Hay

[http://www.amazon.com/Enterprise-Model-Patterns-Describing-Version/dp/1935504053](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935504053)

Also:

Global Justice XML Data Model (GJXDM)

https://it.ojp.gov/jxdm/

National Information Exchange Model (NIEM)

https://www.niem.gov/aboutniem/Pages/niem.aspx