# New to Data Warehouses - should all data exist in one database?

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse

I work for a local Police Force, which has lots of information about People and Vehicles in lots of different data sources.  The organization wants a facility to be able to search these systems centrally.  For example, they enter a name and date of birth into a webpage and it searches all data sources (20) and shows the results on the webpage.

I have built this quite quickly and tested it.  The main problem is that it is slow because:

> 1) There are 20 different databases to search 2) The databases are
>   optimised for selects and inserts as they are OLTP databases

I have created a simple project in Visual Studio Analysis services i.e. there is one data source, a few dimensions, a few hierarchies and a cube.  My questions are:

> 1) Is a Data Warehouse suitable for this scenario?
>
> 2) Should a data warehouse have all information loaded (using ETL) into one database?
>
> 3) Is it bad practive to use ASP.NET to use information in a data warehouse i.e. should you use reporting tools like SSRS and Business Objects etc.
>
> 4) Would you have one dimesnion per database?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Yes.  Use as many tables as you need in a [star schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema). 3) It depends on how much data make up your fact tables.  You'll get better performance with a database and reporting tools designed for data warehouses.  4) Probably more than one.  Ask your police officers what questions they would ask of your magical data warehouse.  I think they would almost always mention the dimensions of location and time.  (Sample request: Number of stolen cars retrieved in the 5th precinct in June, July, and August between 2 am and 6 am.)

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341752/standard-database-schema-for-police-law-enforcement-related-work/17351929#17351929

Answer (score 2):

Data warehouses exist specifically for the purpose of making flexible information retrieval from OLTP data more efficient and manageable.

OLTP databases are structured for efficient data maintenance.  Data retrieval often has different requirements.  Your scenario is probably an excellent candidate for **star schema** or **snowflake schema**.

Whether you have one star or snowflake depends on how many **facts** exist in your OLTP data.  If the only fact that you are tracking (or reporting) are *contacts* between police and the public, then one star or snowflake is probably all you need.  If you have more facts, add more stars (etc.)

Each star or snowflake will have multiple dimensions, typically.  That's OK.  Have as many as are of interest, but have only one *fact* per star/snowflake.

You can use an ETL process to either completely recreate these data warehouse objects either entirely each time or piecemeal on a nightly basis (or other timeframe).  It all depends on your requirements.  The important things to keep in mind are:

- Keep your reporting data and your OLTP data separate if reporting is going to get in the way of transactional processing.
- Be prepared to recreate your data warehouses or resynchronize them periodically, because every time you keep two copies of some data, they will sooner or later get out of synch and someone in the business will yell at someone in IT over it.

There are lots of good tools for doing *ad hoc* reporting on data warehouses.  These can be very useful for exploring data to find things that are interesting.  However, these tools can be complicated and even sometimes inefficient.  Therefore it is a common practice to "institutionalize" very frequently used reports by having them built as standard queries using a stored procedure or similar programmatic approach.  These kinds of reports can be presented using ASP.NET or your web language of choice, bypassing *ad hoc* reporting tools.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is a Data Warehouse suitable for this scenario?

Yes, but you will probably want to use a database brand with good Full Text Search support, to get good results from users' searches.

> 2) Should a data warehouse have all information loaded (using ETL)
>   into one database?

Probably yes. You should distinguish between 'database' and 'database server', as some database servers support multiple databases ;) Your priority is to facilitate analysis for users. If they have to switch databases all the time, they will find that annoying.

> 3) Is it bad practive to use ASP.NET to use information in a data
>   warehouse i.e. should you use reporting tools like SSRS and Business
>   Objects etc.

No, it is not a bad practice, but you will probably find tools like SSRS easier to use for reports etc.

> 4) Would you have one dimesnion per database?

No, you would generally have more than one dimension table per fact table. You almost certainly want at least a date dimension for each fact table.

See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45655/what-are-measures-and-dimensions-in-cubes/45669#45669